# Pass dynamically created html table row innertext id via row click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html-table, click

I have a `htmltable` that is dynamically created. I have made the rows clickable. 
I need to pass the row innertext id to the script that fires when the row is clicked.

`htmltable`:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
     <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>other info</th>
     </tr>
    <tr>
         <td class='table_row_click'>11</td>
        <td class='table_row_click'>item 2</td>
        <td class='table_row_click'>lmfao</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='table_row_click'>22</td>
        <td class='table_row_click'>item 2</td>
        <td class='table_row_click'>lol</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Click event:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
           $(".table_row_click").click(function (e) {

//I need to use the clicked row ID here for something 

            });
       });
```

Comment: Your rows don't have ids?  If you're after the innerText of the td, then that's just `e.target.innerText`

Comment: Yes i apologise. I require the  inner text id, in this example if i clicked the first row i would require the id "11".

Comment: That looks like it will work thank you. Ill try it now.

Comment: actually, how will i specify with td has the inner text i want? as i can click any td on that row to fire the event

Comment: `e` is the event that was generated by clicking a particular element.  `e.target` is the element the event originated from.

Comment: I understand that. Though what happens when i have  class='table_row_click' in each td for the row. How would i get just the inner text of the first td in that row click? 
Something like: e.target[0].innerText

Comment: You would get the text from the first td, when you click the first td..., because that's what the `e.target` would be.

Comment: yes but what if i click the second td on the same row?

Comment: So are you wanting the text of the first td, regardless of which td clicked in the row?

Comment: Yes. I was thinking i might need to get the parent element on the td click. and then once i have the tr then get the first child innerhtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(e.target).closest('tr').find('td').first().text();
```

You can navigate up to the parent tr, find the td elemements, get the first one, and get its text.

Using `closest('tr')` will work if the class is on the td or tr level, as `closest()` can match on itself.

Comment: Perfect mate. Thank you very much